# Serialization. Can't load object

Tags: java, serialization

I want to load my class Floyd and use its method FW, but Intellij write cannot resolve symbol a. I wrote "import.io*" and "implements Serializable" in the class Floyd

```
    import java.io.*;

public class jj {
    public void smth() {

        Floyd fw = new Floyd();
        try {
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("Floyd.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
            os.writeObject(fw);
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


        try{

            ObjectInputStream osNew = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Floyd.ser"));
            Floyd a = (Floyd) osNew.readObject();
            osNew.close();
        } catch (Exception ex1){
            ex1.printStackTrace();
        }

        a.FW();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `a.FW()` inside the second try statement

```
try
{
     ObjectInputStream osNew = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Floyd.ser"));
     Floyd a = (Floyd) osNew.readObject();
     a.FW()
     osNew.close();
} catch (Exception ex1){
     ex1.printStackTrace();
}
```

You have initialized the variable inside the try block so visibility of the `osNew` will not be out of the try block so that IDE intimate that `cannot resolve symbol a`